# To be vs to have describing state

Tags: comparative-linguistics

In English, when describing a personal state, the verb be is used often. For example in English, using be: "I am scared," compared to the German, using have: "Ich habe Angst." Is there any functional difference? German has a word for scared, "erschrocken," so why "Ich habe Angst" over "Ich bin erschrocken"?

Comment: Erschrocken doesn't mean afraid, it means startled.

Comment: "I am scared" uses a passive participle, while "I have fear" uses a noun.

Comment: Judging from the way relative "have" clauses reduce, "have" is equivalent to "be with" ("the man who has a limp" = "the man with a limp").  So the difference between "have" and "be" is merely syntactic.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually be a question at the moment